# HowTo: Return an object from a (static) method?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I'm building a `WinForms` application using `C# 2.0` for a Job Scheduler.

Wrote a `public class Job` in `Program.cs` defining the `Job object`.

```
//Class for defining Job object and its properties 
public class Job
{
    private int IntJobID;
    public int JobID
    {
        get {return IntJobID;}
        set {IntJobID = value;}
    }
    private string StrJobName;
    public string JobName
    {
        get { return StrJobName; }
        set { StrJobName = value; }
    }
    //Several other properties defined here. 
}
```

Also wrote a `public static class ApplicationName` in `Program.cs` for containing application-wide config variables and all helper methods.

```
//Static Class for Global Properties and Global Methods 
//*****************************************************
public static class ApplicationName
{
    //Global Properties 
    //***************************
    public static string ConfigFilePath = "D:\\ApplicationName\\conf\\ApplicationName.ini"; 
    public static string DBFilePath = "D:\\ApplicationName\\data\\ApplicationName.xml"; 
    //Global Methods 
    //************************
    public static void HelperMethod1(Args)
    {
    }
    public static string HelperMethod2(Args)
    {
    }
    public static Job GetJobByID(int JobID)
    {
        XmlDocument XMLDB = new XmlDocument(); XMLDB.Load(DBFilePath);
        Job ObjJob = new Job();
        ObjJob.JobName = XMLDB.SelectSingleNode("/ApplicationName/Job[JobID=" + JobID.ToString() + "]/JobName").InnerText.Trim();
        //Several other properties are retrieved from the DB and set to the object here. 
        return ObjJob;
    }

}
```

One of the helper methods `GetJobByID` in the `public static class ApplicationName` is required to create/instantiate a `Job` object and return the same. I believe this is possible, a method within `ClassA` creating and returning an instance/object of `ClassB`.

Note: This method is meant for access from other forms such as Form1.cs, Form2.cs, etc. in the following way. To my knowledge, this is also allowed and is accepted practice.

```
private void FormAddEditJob_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int SelectedJobID = Convert.ToInt32(this.Tag);
    //Creating an instance of the Job Class 
    //Assigning the value of the Job object returned by GetJobByID method 
    Job JobToEdit = ApplicationName.GetJobByID(SelectedJobID);
    TextBoxJobID.Text = SelectedJobID.ToString();
    TextBoxJobName.Text = JobToEdit.JobName; 
}
```

PROBLEM: The `object` returned by `GetJobByID` method is not getting stored in the object reference `JobToEdit`. Or even possible that the `GetJobByID` method does not return an object appropriately / as expected. What am I doing wrong here? Is this not the right way to return an object?

Comment: There is nothing essentially wrong with your code, other than there's no need to initialise `JobToEdit`, you could just do: `Job JobToEdit = MedImmuneBJM.GetJobByID(SelectedJobID);`

Comment: What is `MedImmuneBJM`? Shouldn't you be calling it with `ApplicationName.GetJobByID(SelectedJobID)`?

Comment: @DionV.: Yes, sorry about the typo. I have edited the static class name.

Comment: @prgSRR Are you sure the XML select is working correctly?

Comment: @DavidG: I have tried it that way as well. Same result. The `JobToEdit` reference stays null.

Comment: What do you mean by "the object is not getting stored in `JobToEdit`"? Is it `null`? Have you checked that `OldJob` does contain what you expect when you return it in `GetJobById`?

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, I have tested individually that the Xml/Xpath is working as expected. I mean, they *do* fetch the expected values.

Comment: Oh OK, it is `null`. Check in the debugger that your static method returns a correct instance of your object.

Comment: @prgSRR Ok, no problem. Have you tried debugging what `return ObjJob` gives? Is it the value you wanted?

Comment: @PatriceGahide: Yes, the `JobToEdit` reference stays null.

Comment: _Several other properties are retrieved from the DB and set to the object here._ Could you show this code? Something wrong could be in there.

Comment: We must be missing some code here, there is something else getting in the way.

Comment: _stays null_? But is `ObjJob` null when you quit the static method? You need to check this with the debugger or output it somewhere for checking _before_ leaving `GetJobById`.

Comment: @Everyone: I am trying to debug and see what is essentially returned by the `GetJobByID` method. Will post my findings asap.

Comment: @Everyone: I found the problem. One of the statements `ObjJob.PropertyName = XMLDB.SelectSingleNode()` in the `GetJobByID` method was throwing an exception, due to fetching null values from the DB, thereby resulting in the `ObjJob` object being returned as null. Found this by debugging line by line.

Comment: @Everyone: So all of your findings were bang on target..!!!! Thanks so much for looking into this. I was very doubtful about a static class returning an object of another class in the first place, wasn't sure if it works that way, so I wasn't looking in the right place to find the problem. Thanks again for all your efforts!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue identified and resolved.

One of the statements `ObjJob.PropertyName = XMLDB.SelectSingleNode()` in the `GetJobByID` method was throwing an exception, due to fetching null values from the DB, thereby resulting in the `ObjJob` object being returned as null. Found this by debugging line by line.